# Mysqli Update not working properly

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {

    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE Cube SET xValue=15 WHERE Index=1";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

mysqli_close($conn);
```

This seems like it should be pretty straight forward, but for some reason, the `xValue` field won't change, and I get no errors whatsoever. Been trying this for too long.

Comment: `Index` 1 really exists?

Comment: Index is a reserved word. Use backticks `\`Index\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as u_mulder said, index is a reserved word in mySQL so you got 2 options:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Cube SET xValue=15 WHERE Cube.Index=1";
```

or

```
$sql = "UPDATE Cube SET xValue=15 WHERE `Index`=1";
```

Comment: Wow... thank you so much for the quick replies. It makes sense now, and I feel like I should have seen that. It worked like a champ (I changed the column name). Thank you guys so much.